# Allow jQuery accordion sorting for few sections

Tags: jquery

I have an accordion and I am allowing to sort them. But for some section I do not want to allow sort and for some I want to allow sort. Is there any built in option to achieve this goal. I will appreciate any help. Following is my code

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    header: "> div > h3",
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    activate: function( event, ui){  
        //this fixes any problems with sorting if panel was open (remove to see what I am talking about)
        if(sorting)
            $(this).sortable("refresh");   
    }
})
.sortable({
    handle: "h3",
    value: "ui-state-highlight",
    start: function( event, ui ){
        //change bool to true
        sorting=true;

        //find what tab is open, false if none
        active = $(this).accordion( "option", "active" ); 

        //possibly change animation here
        $(this).accordion( "option", "animate", { easing: 'swing', duration: 0 } );

        //close tab
        $(this).accordion({ active:false });
        unloadEditors();
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );

        //possibly change animation here; { } is default value
        $(this).accordion( "option", "animate", { } );

        //open previously active panel
        console.log($(this).accordion);
        $(this).accordion( "option", "active", "none" );
        /*loadEditors();*/

        //change bool to false
        sorting=false;
    },
     update: function(event, ui) {
         return;
        var params = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var pageUrl = $("#orderUrl").val();
        dataString = 'ordering='+params;            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
        }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: share with us what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Aisha Please post your code here or jsfiddle??????

Comment: There is a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360904/dynamically-enable-disable-jquery-sortable-item

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have placed my code here.

Comment: Have you tried "items" as noted in the documentation? http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Thanks @timSPQR I will check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle where it works - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/93b9P/4/).

Just put a class on those items to be sorted and add "items: ".yourclass" to the sortable function.

JS

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
                           collapsible: true,
                            active: false
                           });

$("#accordion").sortable({
       items: ".sortme"
});
```